# Unable to debug Office javascript add-in

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to debug an Office Add-In and having issues. I'm in unfamiliar territory, being a VBA developer. I have a very small add-in for Excel and trying to debug locally. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and have Office 365 (Monthly Channel, v2002). Starting with a project template, I've altered it for my uses. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and I've read through a LOT of documentation on it.

My assumption at the moment is my manifest isn't configured correctly. When I debug from VS the task pane loads I get this text in the taskpane:

> ADD-IN ERROR
>   This add-in is no longer available: add-ins inserted
>   during development are only available during debugging from Visual
>   Studio. Please open your project in Visual Studio and re-run your
>   application or deploy your add-in into a valid catalog and re-insert.

I added a 'Manifest' folder and shared it with myself and loaded my manifest file in there, however, no add-ins show up when I look, which is why I'm assuming my manifest isn't correct. Can someone please point me in the right direction? [Here is a link to my manifest.](https://github.com/DataAutoPros/Excel-Web-Table-of-Contents/blob/master/Excel%20Web%20Table%20of%20Contents/Excel%20Web%20Table%20of%20ContentsManifest/Excel%20Web%20Table%20of%20Contents.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sideloading an add-in by pressing F5 in Visual Studio is a different way of loading from adding the manifest to a network share and installing the add-in. If you are using F5, you don't need to be doing the network share thing.

Your manifest has `~remoteAppUrl` as the domain for some URLs, but it has `localhost:3000` as the domain in some other URLs, and it has `www.dataautopros.com` for others. I suspect that one or both of these last 2 URLs is *not* pointing to a server that's up and running. The `~remoteAppUrl` is automatically replaced by VS, when you press F5, with the domain of a local IIS hosted website, usually something like `localhost:43300`. (It is probably *not* `localhost:3000`.) You should stick with this `~remoteAppUrl` domain while you are developing with VS and sideloading with F5. When your add-in is done and you are ready for staging, host the add-in's files in a staging server and update the URLs in the manifest to use the server's domain. Then change the `<Id>` GUID in the manifest to a different random GUID. Then put that revised manifest in the network shared folder and install the add-in.